# 404 Error while accessing API with tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

Just started with TastyPie to expose the data. Trying to tie together resources using tastypie.Api for urls.py.

But I get this error when I try to access them through `localhost:api/**resource.`

my api.py:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from idg.models.molecule_dictionary import MoleculeDictionary


class MoleculeDictionaryResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = MoleculeDictionary.objects.all()
        # resource_name = 'moleculedictionary'
```

my url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include, patterns
from idg.api import MoleculeDictionaryResource
from django.contrib import admin
from tastypie.api import Api
from . import views

dictionary_resource = MoleculeDictionaryResource()
# private_api = Api(api_name='private')
# private_api.register(MoleculeDictionaryResource(), canonical=True)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # url(r'^exports/', include('data_exports.urls', namespace='data_exports')),
    url(r'^api/', include(dictionary_resource.urls)),
]
```

Error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/moleculedictionary/?format=json

Using the URLconf defined in django_root.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^__debug__/
    xadmin/
    ^idg/
    ^comments/
    ^admin/

The current URL, api/moleculedictionary/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Any suggestions ? I am not sure where I made a mistake. I have followed the tutorial (https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment line

```
resource_name = 'moleculedictionary'
```

in Your `api.py` file.

Comment: `"The resource_name within the Meta class is optional. If not provided, it is automatically generated off the classname, removing any instances of Resource and lowercasing the string. So EntryResource would become just entry." ` -from the tutorial But even with the resource nam I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private_api = Api(api_name='v1')
private_api.register(MoleculeDictionaryResource(), canonical=True)


url(r'^api/', include(private_api.urls)),
```

Then you should be able to access it with `/api/v1/`

Comment: The error message I have on my post is all the error I get. No traceback. Sorry I am still a learner but I think the `urlconf` doesn't look for /api is the problem. `Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/moleculedictionary/?format=json

Using the URLconf defined in django_root.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^__debug__/
    xadmin/
    ^idg/
    ^comments/
    ^admin/

The current URL, api/moleculedictionary/, didn't match any of these.
`

Comment: Django doesn't even try the `api` pattern. Are you sure you are editing the right `urls.py`?

Comment: mysite/myproject/urls.py is where I have got my urls. Is this right?

Comment: OKIE!  Got them solved. I had been trying to do them with mysite/myapp/urls.py instead of django_root/urls.py. so @dan-klalsoon you are right. Its to do with right urls.py